# Mechanize module for GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mechanize-python

I tried to make the mechanize module work with GAE, but no luck.
I used latest version of mechanize and the versions that are GAE specific from here
[Python Mechanize + GAEpython code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902079/python-mechanize-gaepython-code).

What I want to do is to login to a website and submit a form.

Example code

```
import mechanize

def mech(uname,passw,txtto,msg):
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.open("http://example.com")
    br.select_form(nr=0)

    br["username"]= uname
    br["password"]= passw
    # br.form

    response = br.submit()
    br.select_form(nr=0)
    # print br.form

    br["txt"] = txtto 
    br["message"] = msg

    br.submit()
    br.back()
```

With mechanize module i get

```
'str' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

and with gaemechanize i get

```
app.mechanize.ClientForm.ControlNotFoundError

ControlNotFoundError: no control matching name 'txt'
```

The code is tested and works outside gae so this is not the problem.
I am using kay framework if this helps.

Comment: Please add a code example, otherwise it's very difficult to help you.

Comment: edited my post to describe the problem better

Comment: what's the output from `print br.form`?

Comment: After some investigation i am sure that it is a gaemechanize issue.

Comment: Please include the complete stacktraces, not just the exception string!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to do this from within a Python GAE app. There are many restrictions on what non-flex-environment GAE code can do (e.g. restrictions on shelling out to other processes, etc.) that do not exist within Google Cloud Functions. **I recommend you try this from a Google Cloud Function.** While there is not (yet) official python support for GCF, there is a [github project](https://github.com/MartinSahlen/cloud-functions-python) that will let you deploy python code to GCF.

I was able to get some similar browser automation code to work in GCF using a Node.js chromium remote plugin, so I would think GCF will work for you as well.

Using a cloud function will also take a lot of load away from your GAE app, so its an all around better solution, as this is really more of a background job.

Whether you decide to use Node.js or Python to write your cloud function, once it's set up you can easily call it from a Pub/Sub or HTTP trigger from within your Python GAE app.

https://cloud.google.com/functions/

Comment: note: because you mention that the code works outside GAE, I would be pretty confident that one of the limitations of standard environment GAE code is preventing this from working