# Can I open an app url in a mechanize browser created inside that app

Tags: google-app-engine, mechanize

I have an url like below

```
http://myappname.appspot.com/openthisurl
```

And in my view.py, I create an gaemechanize browser like this

```
def test(request):
   ###1. CREATE BROWSER
   br = gaemechanize.Browser()

   # set cookies
   cookies = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
   br.set_cookiejar(cookies)

   # browser settings (used to emulate a browser)
   br.set_handle_equiv(True)
   br.set_handle_redirect(True)
   br.set_handle_referer(True)
   br.set_handle_robots(False)
   br.set_debug_http(False)
   br.set_debug_responses(False)
   br.set_debug_redirects(False)
   br.set_handle_refresh(gaemechanize.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
   br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
   ###Open http://myappname.appspot.com/openthisurl inside br

   br.open('http://myappname.appspot.com/openthisurl')
   #Do something
   br.select_form(nr=0) # select the form      


   return Response('Ok')
```

And this is the error I get

Internal Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myappname/4.376620314915414228/kay/app.py", line 371, in get_response
response = view_func(request, **values)

File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myappname/4.376620314915414228/myapp/views.py", line 3669, in test
br.open('http://myappname.appspot.com/openthisurl')

File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myappname/4.376620314915414228/myapp/gaemechanize/_mechanize.py", line 209, in open
return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)

File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myappname/4.376620314915414228/myapp/gaemechanize/_mechanize.py", line 236, in _mech_open
response = UserAgentBase.open(self, request, data)

File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myappname/4.376620314915414228/myapp/gaemechanize/_opener.py", line 194, in open
response = urlopen(self, req, data)

File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
'_open', req)

File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)

File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myappname/4.376620314915414228/myapp/gaemechanize/_googleappengine.py", line 731, in http_open
return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)

File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myappname/4.376620314915414228/myapp/gaemechanize/_googleappengine.py", line 708, in do_open
raise URLError(err)

URLError:

Comment: some fiddling may be required: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902079/python-mechanize-gaepython-code

Comment: no, i think it is not my problem. I changed br.open('http://myappname.appspot.com/openthisurl') to br.open('http://differentapp.appspot.com/test') and the error gone. It seems that I cannot create a browser in a certain app and then visit that app url.